# Receber um LocalDateTime de um formulário html

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Problema :

Estou tentando receber um LocalDateTime deste input dentro de um `@Controller` utlizando um `<form>` que utiliza o Thymeleaf.

```
<input class="form-control" id="dueDate" type="datetime-local" th:field="*{dueDate}"/>
```

Porém sempre retorna `null`, os outros campos estão funcionando perfeitamente.

Objeto utilizado para transferir dados :

```
public class TaskDTO {
     private long id;
     @Size(min=8)
     @NotNull
     private String name;
     @Size(min=8)
     @NotNull
     private String description;
     @NotNull
     private String priority;
     @Size(min=8)
     @NotNull
     private String location;
     private boolean completed;
     @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
     @NotNull
     private LocalDateTime dueDate;


     //getters e setters omitidos
}
```

Creio que não seja tão relevante, mas este é o controller :

```
@PostMapping("/dashboard/task/{id}")
public String TaskForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("taskDTO")TaskDTO taskDTO,BindingResult bidingResult,@PathVariable("id")long id) {
    if(bidingResult.hasFieldErrors()) {
        //
    }
    Project p = projectRepository.findById(id).get();
    Task t = taskDTO.generateTask(p);
    taskRepository.save(t);
    return "main";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabalhar com a nova API de datas do Java 8 no Thymeleaf, são necessárias duas coisas que você pode checar se existem no seu projeto:

1) uma dependência com um módulo extra do Thymeleaf (obs.: a versão dessa dependência deve ser a MESMA da do Thymeleaf atualmente em uso no projeto. Esta que linkei aqui é a mais recente).

```
//Se for projeto Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

//Se for projeto Gradle
compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-java8time', version: '3.0.1.RELEASE'
```

2) uma configuração específica da *engine* do Thymeleaf. No seu caso, possivelmente você já tem esse método, então bastaria incluir a linha indicada:

```
private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect()); //linha a ser adicionada
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    return engine;
}
```

Possivelmente isso resolva seu problema. [Aqui](http://www.baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf) há algumas informações adicionais que você pode dar uma olhada também.

Comment: eu já havia adicionado e configurado esta dependência, por fim acabei por passar uma string e converte-la no servidor.